# Windows command line open pdf and save as txt file

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd

I want to open a pdf file over the command line in Windows 7. Then I want to save the pdf file as a txt file.

I can open a pdf file with a specific programm but then I don't know how i can tell the programm to save the file as a txt file.

thanks for your help.

Comment: [This question](http://superuser.com/questions/294725/pdf-to-text-open-source-command-line-tool) talks about several solutions.

Comment: ok i solved it. 
write in cmd 
path\pdftotext.exe path\nameofpdf.pdf 
then it will crate a txt file on your desktop